# Is there difference in terms of performance between *[data-some-id='XX'] and [data-some-id='XX']?

Tags: css, css-selectors

As the title stated, is there performance difference between

```
*[data-some-id='XX'] {
...
}
```

versus

```
[data-some-id='XX'] {
...
}
```

Comment: Probably not. What tool are you using to measure performance? Could you not do some A/B testing to find out?

Answer (score 1):

[Per specs](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/#the-universal-selector), they are just the same.

> Unless an element is featureless, the presence of a universal selector has no effect on whether the element matches the selector.

> Note: In some cases, adding a universal selector can make a selector easier to read, even though **it has no effect on the matching behavior**.[...]

<sup>emphasis mine</sup>

Comment: I mean, that could be read one of two ways: either that it doesn't change the theoretical "how" (i.e. \*#id and #id both match one or more elements with that ID), or that it doesn't affect the *implementation*. Generally, the spec doesn't describe implementations unless it explicitly says it's about to. Nevertheless, implementation-wise, it's understood that most CSS parsers - at least the ones we can see the source for anyway - simply discard the * when parsing the selector. So the matching implementation is exactly the same, because as far as it's concerned, the input selector is the same.

Comment: Are you saying my *"per specs"* isn't clear enough about this answer approaching only the theoretical aspect of the question? I mean of course it depends on the implementation, I could make my own implementation with something like `if(selector.includes("*[") sleep(314)` to make any answer talking about implementations wrong. The only way to have a fixed answer to that question is by quoting the specs. (And actually, even if the implementations **do** drop the `*`, the simple fact that they had to handle it is an op, but we all know OP doesn't have to care about it: "they're just the same".

Comment: You don't answer a performance question with "per specs" unless the quoted text is explicitly talking about performance issues, or unless you want to extrapolate or draw a conclusion or state an informed opinion about implementations based on what it says. Otherwise the answer might as well not have been posted, because it doesn't answer the question. And of course I know that dropping the * is extra overhead, the reason I didn't mention it is because as you said it doesn't matter - parsing is so much faster than matching that it's practically negligible.

Comment: (If anything, the extra byte of the * has potentially greater impact when more selectors start to use it and the bytes start adding up.)

Comment: That answer states that "per specs" there is no difference to begin with. That's enough to draw the conclusion that there should be no difference in performance (since they're "the same"). I don't get what you're after here... And I disagree about not quoting the specs for performance questions. Looking at what logical ops should be done internally is the best way to have an universal not-too-bad understanding of where performance drawbacks may come from.

Comment: It is not possible to give a definitive answer to any performance question except if this question is asking for a very particular case running in a very particular environment. Or are you saying perf questions should simply not be asked?